# How to make custom shopping cart rule in magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

Apart from all the existing shopping cart rules, we need to add our own attributes in the shopping cart rules and provide discount based on the values of that attribute. Is it possible? How can I do this ? please help me!

Answer (score 0):

1)Catalog >Manage Attributes > Select an attribute & select **"Yes"** in "**Use fOr Promo Rule condiions**"

[image]

2)Go to shopping cart Price rule & you can select that attribute

[image]

Comment: Yeah you are correct but what am I asking is, other than the default attributes under Catalog->Manage Attributes, If we create our own attribute, say a text field attribute like, **product_from** and which may contain a value like **velavasimman**, or from you **vickey colors** then based on these values I need to set shopping cart rules . How can I make it? I tried it, but it goes like we can add a rule by checking whether or not that attribute value **is assigned** but what I want is the first case...

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan please update the question with this requirement.....

Comment: Do what Vickey colors says and then select the attribute. Click on the 'is' link and you get a lot more options. Does that help?